# Show that Petersen Graph minus a vertex is hamiltonian

Tags: graph-theory

I need to show that the Petersen graph minus a vertex is hamiltonian, but now all I can think about is that its vertex degrees are in $\{2,3\}$ and that the order is $n=9$ but I do not know how to continue, can you please help me?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

The [Petersen graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Petersen_graph#Hamiltonian_paths_and_cycles) is vertex-transitive, since it is isomorphic to the [Kneser graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kneser_graph) $KG(5,2)$.
If we remove any vertex, we clearly have a hamiltonian cycle:

[image]